# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.compat'

Tags: python, pandas

I have been working with pandas all the time, but now it suddenly says:

"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.compat'"

when importing it. I didnt (knowlingly) change anything. I already reainstalled it (and pandas-compat). I even created a whole new environment. I still cant import it. Anybody has a clue what this might be? Would reinstalling anaconda help? I feel like some files in my system might be broken. Which ones would I have to delete, to give it a full "python reboot"?
I saw the other threads about it, but nothing helped so far.

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "L:\Python_files\LOPF-KNST.py", line 12, in <module>
    import pypsa

  File "C:\Users\<username>\.conda\envs\PyPSA\lib\site-packages\pypsa\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from . import components, descriptors

  File "C:\Users\<username>\.conda\envs\PyPSA\lib\site-packages\pypsa\components.py", line 31, in <module>
    import pandas as pd

  File "\\...\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import is_numpy_dev as _is_numpy_dev

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.compat'
```

Comment: it imports the first packages from my environment. But when importing the pandas-compat part, it somehow goes into the roaming files? Might that be a problem?

Comment: I just checked that last path, it simply doesnt exist. I feel like all my python files are gone?

Comment: Have you tried (force) re-installing Pandas?

Comment: yes, didnt work.

Comment: If I reinstall Anacondas, will it delete all my python files or will they partly be kept? I feel like I need a complete restart.

Answer (score -1):

You may have several installations of pandas library. So uninstall pandas using
"pip uninstall pandas".
(If on linux use:
" sudo apt-get purge python3-pandas")

and install again.
This helped solve my problem.